# The application of a minimum and maximum force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, equilibrium

There are three blocks - a big block (C) above a horizontal surface that is smooth. A block (A) of mass m is resting on block C, and is also connected to another block (B) of mass m through an ideal string running through a pulley (the pulley is fixed on the upper right corner of the block C).

The question is to find the minimum and maximum force F that can be applied in order to keep the smaller block at rest relative to the bigger block.

I saw the solution of it but couldn't really understand why they would initially consider of **no force** being applied, and for which the block A will slip on C and the block B will move downwards.

They have considered the minimum force needed to prevent slipping to be F, and taking A + B + C as the system and the only external horizontal force on the system as F, they obtained the acceleration of the system.

**If the first main work is to prevent the slipping, then why is acceleration to be obtained in the first place? Further, by considering the individual blocks A and B moving with acceleration, they obtained the forces acting on them.**

**I actually thought that to prevent slipping, we have to consider each of the blocks to be in equilibrium and not accelerating.**

Answer (score 0):

> I actually thought that to prevent slipping, we have to consider each of the blocks to be in equilibrium and not accelerating.

You have provided earlier that the question asks that the small blocks need to be at rest relative to the larger block. To satisfy this scenario, it is not necessary that all the blocks are not accelerating but all the blocks need to have same acceleration.

> If the first main work is to prevent the slipping, then why is acceleration to be obtained in the first place? Further, by considering the individual blocks A and B moving with acceleration, they obtained the forces acting on them.

You will have to calculate the net acceleration of all the three blocks together to find the acceleration of the system in the forward direction. now you can analyze the situation relative to the center of mass of Block C.

Since the COM is accelerating with an acceleration $a = \frac{F}{m_a+m_b+m_c}$, a pseudo-force $F_{pseudo} = m_a \cdot a$ acts on the Block A opposite to the direction of acceleration.
[image: Pseudo Force]

At the critical condition, $F_{pseudo} = T$ where $T = m_b g$ is the tension in the string at equilibrium. This establishes an equilibrium.

> The question is to find the minimum and maximum force F that can be applied in order to keep the smaller block at rest relative to the bigger block.

With the data you have given in the question, it is unclear if there actually is friction between the Blocks A and C. Assuming there is no friction, there is only 1 possible value of $F$ that will keep the situation in equilibrium.

In case there is friction between the blocks,

the minimum force would be $T = \mu m_a g + F_{Pseudo} = m_b g \implies F_{Pseudo} = (m_b - \mu m_a)g$

$\implies m_a \cdot \frac{F_{min}}{m_a+m_b+m_c} = g(m_b - \mu m_a)$
$\implies F_{min} = \frac{g(m_b - \mu m_a) \cdot (m_a+m_b+m_c)}{m_a}$

the maximum force would be $F_{Pseudo} = (\mu m_a + m_b)g$

$\implies m_a \cdot \frac{F_{max}}{m_a+m_b+m_c} = g(m_b + \mu m_a)$
$\implies F_{max} = \frac{g(m_b + \mu m_a) \cdot (m_a+m_b+m_c)}{m_a}$